# How to handle placement of Error messages defined in model

Tags: css

> This is my model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Current password is required")]
    [Remote("IsCorrectOldPassword", "Account", ErrorMessage = "The password you gave is incorrect.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Current Password")]
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Maximum {1} characters are allowed.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New Password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```

> this is my view

```
  <div  style="width: 500px; padding-left: 100px">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "Account", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "AfterSave()", UpdateTargetId = "formcontents" }, new { @id = "formSavePwd" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

@*@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)*@

```
                <table style="width: 100%">

                    @*<caption>Change Password Form</caption>*@

                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.OldPassword)


                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.OldPassword, new { @enabled = true, maxlength = 20, size = 20 })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OldPassword)
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewPassword)

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewPassword)

                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

> when error messages are shown half sentence is displayed in next line , and some times my label text for text box also goes in next line , please tell how can i handle my error placement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link helped me
[styling mvc errors](http://geekswithblogs.net/MightyZot/archive/2013/11/11/styling-asp.net-mvc-error-messages.aspx)

I have made following changes in css

```
.field-validation-error
{
    color: #990000;
    float: left;
    width: auto;  

}
```